# Can a user without admin rights manage object access privileges in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am working with hive 0.14 mainly using beeline.

I am not an admin but I am looking to create a couple of views that the team can use.

We've got a common hive database where everyone has read+write. If I am creating certain tables/views that I don't want other people to be able to drop or modify, is it possible for me to revoke drop/write access for others?

Comment: The topic of "Hive authorization models" would require a 3-days seminar in itself. The"preferred" model has changed over time, and there are alternatives (cf. Ranger or Sentry plug-ins). If you are not an admin indeed, and don't want to look at whatever little documentation is available, then good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access to hive tables depends on HDFS access rights.

Whenever you create a new table `tbl` in database located in  `db`, a new directory `db/tbl` will be created.

If you want to restrict write group access to that directory use `hadoop fs -chmod`, for example:

`hadoop fs -chmod 750 db/tbl`

If you want to find out where tables are located in a database, you can create a table without specifying a location, and run `describe formated tbl`.

You can always check what are the access rights of the tables by running `hadoop fs -ls db`

Regarding views:

> Although Storage Based Authorization can provide access control at the level of Databases, Tables and Partitions, **it can not control authorization at finer levels such as columns and views** because the access control provided by the file system is at the level of directory and files. A prerequisite for fine grained access control is a data server that is able to provide just the columns and rows that a user needs (or has) access to. In the case of file system access, the whole file is served to the user. HiveServer2 satisfies this condition, as it has an API that understands rows and columns (through the use of SQL), and is able to serve just the columns and rows that your SQL query asked for.
>
> [SQL Standards Based Authorization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization) (introduced in Hive 0.13.0, HIVE-5837) can be used to enable fine grained access control. It is based on the SQL standard for authorization, and uses the familiar grant/revoke statements to control access. **It needs to be enabled through HiveServer2 configuration**.
>
> Note that for Hive command line, SQL Standards Based Authorization is disabled. This is because secure access control is not possible for the Hive command line using an access control policy in Hive, because users have direct access to HDFS and so they can easily bypass the SQL standards based authorization checks or even disable it altogether. Disabling this avoids giving a false sense of security to users.

So, in short, [SQL Standards Based Authorization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization) needs to be enabled in the config.

Then you'll be able to use: [`REVOKE`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization#SQLStandardBasedHiveAuthorization-Revoke) on views.

Comment: is that the case too for views?

Comment: @user55570 Yes, if you revoke read access - only you can read the files which means only you can read the table.

Comment: ok, but as far as i can see only a table has related hdfs files. a view does not.

Comment: a "view" is just like a saved query - if you have access to the table/tables accessed in the view - you can use it.

Comment: yes, but can i limit others from dropping/modifying my view?

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. After looking through that link for SQL based authorisation, I am still wondering can a non-admin actually effectively issue a revoke on views that one creates?

Comment: From the documentation it seems so - the creator of a view/table is it's owner, and the owner can grant/revoke privileges. Specifically, ownership is needed to alter or drop a view but only "select" privilege is needed to select from a view.